# Rewriting URL and hiding Subpage Name

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a rewrite in my .htaccess file that sends people from example.com to example.com/home

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ home [L,R=301]
```

How do I do this but then strip the string "home" from the url bar so that it appears to be example.com? I'm not interested in any subdirectories after home as the rest of the site lives in the root.

**Full Context**

```
# Perch Runway
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Turn on RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

# When user goes to the home page send to .com/home and strip /home
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ home [L,R=301]

# Cache Busting
RewriteRule (assets[/])([^.]*).min.+.(css|js)$ $1$2.min.$3

# Perch Runway
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/sub-directory-one|/sub-directory-two) [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /login/core/runway/start.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I get a 404 error

Comment: ok try: `RewriteRule ^/?$ home [L]`

Comment: still get a 404

Comment: home is a subpage - yes there is other rules - updated my answer so you can see context.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?$ home [L]` works fine on my Apache. I think 404 is due to your `/login/core/runway/start.php` which is not handling rewrites cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag, Apache sends a redirect status to the client. The client then requests the new URL (e.g. `http://www.example.com/home`) and displays the new URL.

To avoid this behaviour, you do not send a redirect (e.g. `R`), but silently *rewrite* internally to the new URL. This way Apache sends the contents of the target without notifying the client.

To just rewrite internally from `/` to `/home`, keep the existing rule, but remove the `R` flag

```
RewriteRule ^$ /home [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !home /home%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: I get an internal server error. 

RewriteRule ^$ home [L,R=301] does the job - I just need to hide "home" in the url - I'm not looking to change any subdirectories after home

Comment: I edited the rule, please try again I am] testing it on my side.

Comment: Sorry but I still get an Internal Server Error - I have updated my original answer to give more clarity